# Is it possible to allow user 2 user interaction in Chrome Extension MV3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

I've been dabbling in chrome extension for a while and just recently wondered if it was possible to create, for example, a chat app or allow for users to interact (in some way) using the extension.

Comment: Try to refrain from abbreviating the word "to" with "2" on a programming forum.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done if there is a resource that can be shared between User1 and User2.
For example, `Google Drive`.

1. User1 creates a chat folder in `Google Drive` and makes User2 an editor.
2. User1 writes a message to User1.txt and User2 reads it.
3. User2 writes a message to User2.txt and User1 reads it.

Program the above as an extension.